# "Хватиться что-то" — это вообще в какие-то рамки разве укладывается?

Tags: грамотная-речь, склонение, падежи

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я бы сказал исключительно *хватились собачонк**и**,* то есть в родительном падеже. А что думаете вы?

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю, что хватиться можно также *о собачонке*. И даже *о собачонку* или *за собачонку* (если забыть о стихотворении Маршака и придумать подходящий контекст). Но *хватиться собачонку* просто так, без предлога, нельзя, конечно.

Answer (score 1):

Согласно словарю управления в русском языке, глагол "хватиться" сочетается с существительным в родительном падеже ("хватились собачонки"), устаревшей считается форма с предложным падежом ("хватились о собачонке").

> и тогда только, не видя Дубровского, хватился о нём (Пушкин)

Answer (score 1):

"Хватиться Собачонку" укладывается только в рамки несклоняемой румынской или португальской фамилии. Возвратный глагол направлен на *себя* и потому не может действовать как переходный, т. е. иметь дополнение в *винительном* падеже.

Comment: Вот-вот, ха-ха) Спасибо, Александр!

Comment: *Возвратный глагол направлен на себя и потому не может действовать как переходный* - Как насчет *Слушайся маму!*? Или вы настаиваете исключительно на ортодоксальном варианте "слушайся мамы"? На самом-то деле все сложнее с этой вашей формулировкой. Я разберу этот пример  - как только найду силы написать свой ответ. Но мне тут интересно общее мнение.